# c++ error: :-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - in Qt-Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i'm working on an exercise at uni and every time i try to compile the main.cpp i got always the same error.

actor.h:

```
class Actor {
public:
Actor();
Actor(double x0, double y0);
void move();
double pos_x();
double pos_y();

static const int ARENA_W = 500;
static const int ARENA_H = 500;
};
```

plane.h (subclass of actor):

```
class Plane:Actor
{
public:
Plane();
Plane(double x0, double y0);
void move();
double pos_x();
double pos_y();

//int dx = 5;
static const int W = 50;
static const int H = 20;

private:
double x, y;
};
```

plane.cpp

```
#include "plane.h"
#include "actor.h"

Plane::Plane(double x0, double y0)
{
this ->x = x0;
this ->y = y0;
//this -> dx;
}

void Plane::move()
{
x = x + 2.5 ;
}

 double Plane::pos_x()
{
return x;
}
double Plane::pos_y()
{
return y;
}
```

main.cpp

```
include "plane.h"
include"actor.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Plane plane1(25.0, 5.0);
plane1.move();
double x = plane1.pos_x();
double y = plane1.pos_y();
cout << x << " , " << y<<endl;
}
```

i saw there are many questions about this problem but i didn't fix it.
can you help me please()?
thank you

Comment: Please, post exact error

Comment: Exactly what symbol(s) were not found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488801/make-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You're missing the implementation of the `Actor::Actor()`, which is needed because `Plane` is a child class of `Actor` and you need to construct `Actor` before you construct `Plane` - as it's trivial; you can use `Actor::Actor() {}` in `actor.h` and it should address the

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Actor::Actor()", referenced from:
      Plane::Plane(double, double) in plane.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [4_3_lista_personaggi] Error 1
16:42:54: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project 4_3_lista_personaggi (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make" -----> this is the error

Comment: @Petesh i didn't understand what you mean, could you explain me better?

Comment: @Petesh i added Actor::Actor() {} in actor.h but its still not working

Comment: Added, or replaced the line `Actor();`? You should have replaced it with `Actor() {}`

Comment: @Petesh i replaced it. Now the error is: - 4_3_lista_personaggi/actor.h:7: error: extra qualification on member 'Actor'
    Actor::Actor() {
    ~~~~~~~^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared a class `Actor` in `actor.h`:

```
class Actor {
    public: Actor();
};
```

This means that you're going to write some code that will define this construction. This would typically end up in an `Actor.cpp` file.

If you attempt to construct an `Actor` without having this implementation, you will get an error from the linker because you're missing the default constructor.

Now you've declared a `Plane` that's a subclass of an `Actor`:

```
class Plane : Actor {
};
```

and you've defined a non-default constructor:

```
Plane::Plane(double, double) {
   // does something
}
```

As `Plane` is a subclass of `Actor`, there's an implicit construction of a default `Actor` as part of the construction of `Plane`, and as you declared that there would be an implementation, the linker is expecting it. As you never defined it in the code, the linker fails at this point.

The somewhat simplistic solution is to add a trivial constructor in `actor.h`; namely:

```
class Actor {
public:
Actor() {} // replace the ; with {}
Actor(double x0, double y0);
void move();
double pos_x();
double pos_y();

static const int ARENA_W = 500;
static const int ARENA_H = 500;
};
```

> Now, as for behaviours here - none of the `move`, `pos_x` or `pos_y` methods are declared `virtual`, so they're not being overloaded in `Plane`; they're simply being replaced. This may come up later in your course.

Comment: so should i write an actor.cpp file ?

Comment: If you intend to implement proper constructors, and have implementations of `move` and `pos_x` and `pos_y`, then adding an `actor.cpp` file would be an approach; however as I've commented in the answer already; because the code is trivial, implementations in the `.h` file are perfectly acceptable as written.

Comment: Make sure you didn't write `Actor::Actor() {}` in the `actor.h` file, but simply wrote `Actor() {}` in the file - this is the reason for the `extra qualification` warning (and I can't edit my comment to replace the mis-written text).