# How to fix "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" C++ compiler error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm working on a school assignment. I have Wallet.h and Main.cpp
In the Wallet.h I have a public:

```
static std::map<std::string, double> currencies;
```

and `Wallet();`

In Main.cpp I'm trying to use this currencies map as such:

```
std::map<std::string, double> currencies = wallet.currencies;`
```

I do not get any warnings in the code, but when I try to compile I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "Wallet::currencies",
> [...] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error:
> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm not sure what is wrong, probably it's not correct how I'm trying to use currencies.
Can someone help?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Most likely your question is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110487/undefined-reference-to-a-static-member

Comment: step 1: realize that "undefined symbol" errors are not _compiler_ but _linker_ errors...

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say anything specific without a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it seems that with

```
std::map<std::string, double> currencies = wallet.currencies;
```

you define a global ***non***-member variable instead of a `Wallet` member.

You need to explicitly define it as a member of the `Wallet` class:

```
std::map<std::string, double> Wallet::currencies = wallet.currencies;
//                            ^^^^^^^^
//    Note scope as Wallet member here
```

Comment: Well, the linker error contains sufficient information to know that it is a member of class and the definition provided isn't. Of course, the original question should still include all relevant bits which it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried std::map<std::string, double> Wallet::currencies, it's not working. I'm not sure how to share the relevant bits without sharing the whole project. It's quite big and not public.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured, I needed to add `std::map<std::string, double> Wallet::currencies = {{"USD", 10000}};`  to Wallet.cpp to default the values. Wallet was empty.

This question pointed me in the direction of finding the problem:
[c++ error: :-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - in Qt-Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870167/c-error-1-error-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-in-qt-creat)